# How to reduce 48 V to 32 V on a PCB?

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, heat

I need to supply an evaluation kit (a motor driver) at 32 VDC +- 10 % from a 48 VDC battery. In the datasheet it is stated:

> The power supply has to be thermally designed to withstand the nominal ratings and also needs to be able to supply the peak power during at least 100 ms, the current peaks having a duty cycle of 10%. Nominal power input rating: 60 W at 32 VDC. Peak power input rating: 150 W at 32 VDC.

I am thus looking at a 48 VDC to 32 VDC converter that can output a current of 1.88 A (and absorb peaks at 4.69 A).

At first I was thinking there would exist board-mount DC-DC converters that would do the trick, such as [this one](https://uk.farnell.com/multicomp-pro/mprb4824ld-30w/dc-dc-converter-24v-1-25a/dp/3652803). But I have not found one that suits my requirements, do you think it actually exists? It looks like 32 VDC is not a very common voltage.

One solution I have found is a brick DC-DC converter like [this one](https://www.digikey.be/en/products/detail/recom-power/RPA300E-4832S-N-H/15287102). But it gets extremely hot even without load and it needs an air cooling system which will be hard for me to implement.

Do you think there are other solutions? How would you solve this? It is the first time I have to deal with quite high voltages and currents so I am a bit lost...

Comment: It would be easier and cheaper to get (or build) a motor driver that accepts 48V...

Comment: That is what I plan to do in the second phase of my project, but in the first place I have to use this kit to validate the motors. :)

Comment: Just for validation? Got a 30V 5A bench power supply?

Comment: RE: "it gets extremely hot even without load"...You need a 150 W supply (or very near to it). Even at 90% efficiency it will generate 15 W of heat. You will need to find a cooling solution regardless of what circuit you choose.

Comment: A "32V" motor driver would be a very good match for a "24V" battery which can easily be around 28V fully charged ( 8 cell LFP max 29.2V, 12 cell lead acid, etc). At least, that's how I'd solve it.

Comment: The kit is sold with a 32 V power supply but I have to use the 48 V battery (it is a specification). 
Well 150 W is only required during peaks, most of the time it would consume 60 W. The brick DC-DC has an efficiency of 95 % which is great because it means only 3 W of dissipation. But on the other hand it needs to be cooled even without load (it consumes about 100 mA under 48 VDC).

Comment: Nitpicking: _"absorb peaks at 4.69 A"_ The word you are looking for is supply, not absorb.

Comment: It is not a good idea to regulate voltage to high current devices that are not picky about voltage like motors. You really do not want to take this approach. As you have found out, it makes for overblown, inefficient, complex, hot designs that perform worse. Match the motor and motor driver to the voltage instead.

Answer (score 3):

> *But I have not found one that suits my requirements, do you think it
> actually exists ? It looks like 32 VDC is not a very common voltage.*

If you can't buy one then build one (remembering that this site doesn't recommend off-the-shelf products).

$$\color{red}{\text{So, if you design one and build it, then it exists}}$$

> *Do you think there are other solutions? How would you solve this?*

Read on...

This [chip](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc7801.pdf) isn't far off from what you need: -

[image]

Or maybe adjust the output voltage on [this one](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3840fa.pdf) to suit: -

[image]